# The idiomatic way to handle or prevent "race condition" in elixir channels

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Sorry for the dumb question. But I am a newbie in elixir came from golang.

I really love elixir and FP style, I try to implement some basic feature and had an issue with race conditions on websocket connection. For example, in golang I resolved it with Mutex, but it's not FP style.

Initial problem:
Several WebSocket connections, waiting for the group of 5. And then randomly shuffle people. In this case, I had some problems with "race condition". Same people to different groups etc.

What is the right idiomatic way to solve this in Elixir?

Thank you for your help. And sorry again for a dumb question.

I will share my ugly code snippet)

For example, two concurrent users join lobby channel I track they joined via presence. After it when some of the user send "match" event I find other online users in the lobby until there is more than one.

```
defp match(user_id, online_list) when length(online_list) < 1
```

Then I create a room and send room_id to them. But when two users send a match I have two rooms, because of race condition.

I want to have one common room for a group of users. In lang such go, I could use mutex and share. But I don't know how to implement this logic in elixir.

Right now if Alice call the event and I have enough user for Alice, but Bob call this event at the same time and he also had enough users. But they need to be in a common group, not in two separate ones. They intersect

```
def match(user_id) do
    user_id = Integer.to_string(user_id)
    match(user_id, [])
  end

  defp match(user_id, online_list) when length(online_list) < 1 do
    new_online_list =
      RchatWeb.Presence.list("room:lobby")
      |> Map.delete(user_id)
      |> Map.keys()
    match(user_id, new_online_list)
  end

  defp match(first_user_id, online_list) do
    second_user_id = Enum.random(online_list) |> String.to_integer()
    second_room_id = Accounts.get_user_room_id(second_user_id)
    {:ok, room} = cond do
      is_nil(second_room_id) -> create_room()
      true -> {:ok, get_room!(second_room_id)}
    end
    # Try to fix race condition with presence or channels
    {:ok, first_user} =
      Accounts.get_user!(first_user_id)
      |> Accounts.update_user(%{room_id: room.id})
    {:ok, second_user} =
      Accounts.get_user!(second_user_id)
      |> Accounts.update_user(%{room_id: room.id})
    ids = [first_user.id, second_user.id]
    {:ok, room.hash, ids}
  end
```

Comment: Show the code please, it’s extremely hard to understand what the issue is from your description.

Comment: ++ code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir do not have mutable state, so the concept of local mutex is pointless there. Distributed locks can have some use-cases, but that is very different thing from the local mutexes.

Remember that each process is always sequential, so if I understand your use case correctly you want something like:

```rb
defmodule Queue do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])

  def register_and_wait(pid),
    do: GenServer.call(pid, {:register, self()}, :infinity)

  def init(_), do: {:ok, []}

  def handle_call({:register, pid}, from, participants) do
    new_state = [{pid, from} | participants]
    case length(new_state) do
      5 ->
        shuffled = Enum.shuffle(new_state)
        {pids, refs} = Enum.unzip(shuffled)

        for ref <- refs, do: GenServer.reply(ref, {:ready, pid})

        {:noreply, shuffled}

      n when n < 5 ->
        {:reply, {:wait, 5 - n}, new_state}

      _ ->
        {:reply, :overcrowded, participants}
    end
  end
end
```

Now `register_and_wait/1` will register current process and lock as long as needed (beware of infinite lock) for as much processes as needed (5 in this case, but that could be made configurable). It is impossible to have deadlock as long as there is enough processes to be registered and then the `{:ready, shuffled_list_of_pids}` will be returned.

Comment: Thank you, I shared my code snippet to better describe the initial problem.